# Encrypt / decrypt Yii URLs

Tags: php, yii

I need a way to decrypt encrypted URL request parameters into the original Yii `controller/action` path. Example:

From: `http://www.site.com/feh923rfj932` (encrypted)
To: `http://www.site.com/api/view/1` (decrypted)

Is there some CUrlManager router callback I can use to implement a decrypt method?

Comment: That depends. How did you get from "api/view/1" to "feh923rfj932"?

Comment: from request, urls came already encrypted.

Comment: So you get requests à la "http://www.site.com/feh923rfj932", and you think that "feh923rfj932" is a somehow encrypted version of a URL that you can route as usual, and you don't know how it's encrypted? Did I get that right?

Comment: No. I know how it encrypted(i have decrypt algorithm). I don't know how "to say" to route what `feh923rfj932` is a `api/view/1`

Comment: I think the question is, what is the encryption function. MD5? SHA? Other?

Comment: omg... guys encryption(with reverse decryption) not hashing. Look at update

Comment: Sorry, you're right, hashing and encryption are not the same thing. That said, your question update does not really make anything clearer to me... do you have a decrypter for your English? ;) I think my answer should work for you to do whatever kind of encryption you need though, good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Yii provides an easy way to implement your own URL logic using [Custom Url Classes](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#using-custom-url-rule-classes) "callbacks".

Basically, you will declare a new rule that points to your new decoder/encoder class:

```
'rules' => array(
  '' => 'site/index', // normal URL rules
  array( // your custom URL handler
    'class' => 'application.components.CustomUrlRule',
  ),
),
```

Your URL class will look something like this:

```
class CustomUrlRule extends CBaseUrlRule {

  public function createUrl($manager,$route,$params,$ampersand) {
    return your_encrypt_method($route);
  }

  public function parseUrl($manager,$request,$pathInfo,$rawPathInfo) {
    return your_decrypt_method($pathInfo);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yup, but that's just encrypt the route, not including the params.. The example from the question is encrypt including the params.